# Connect LM324 to L293D

Tags: voltage, current, motor, comparator, l293d

I would like to control the motor direction using an LM324(as a window comparator) & an L293D. the two output pins of my LM324 go to the Logic input pins of the L293D. The output voltage of the LM324 is 10.58V. According to the datasheet of the L293D the maximum input voltage to the logic pins should be less than equal to 7V. I cannot seem to understand the current requirements of the L293D using the datasheet. I wish to find the correct value of resistance wish is to be connected between the LM324 output pins to the input pins of the L293D.

Comment: Find an open collector comparator like the LM339 and pull the output up to your 5V rail. Done. Op amps make garbage comparators anyway.

Comment: My PCB is already built around the LM324. But I can still add resistors to it.

Comment: if you dont know how to interface logic, you certainly dont know how to interface and control a motor.  Define the overall interface specs first

Comment: Regardless, don't use an antiquated, lossy L293D. See the "Related" column to the right which is literally chock full of explanations why.

Comment: The L293D & LM324 have already been added to the PCB. There is still scope to add resistors between them.

Comment: Schematic Please

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment)

As I stated in a comment with your previous question, the input current requirements are in the datasheet section 6.5 part I inserted there (Iih and Iil):

[image]

What is it that you don't understand?